# Cannot find symbol method setAnimationListener

Tags: java, android, animation

I am trying to make an animation to run after another animation ends, in several forums I found the same answer, to use setAnimationListener, but I keep getting the cannot find symbol error, what is wrong?

```
public class Juego extends Activity
{
    private AnimationDrawable animacion, loop;
    private MediaPlayer miPlayer;
    private int order = 1;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_juego);
    ImageView video = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.secuencia);
    video.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation_drawable_start);
    animacion = (AnimationDrawable)video.getBackground();
    animacion.start();
    animacion.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {


        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AnimationDrawable` does not provide method `setAnimationListener`:

[`AnimationDrawable` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html)

The one you are looking for belongs to `Animation`:

[`Animation` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setAnimationListener%28android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener%29)